# Aws PHP SDK S3 RequestTimeTooSkewed Error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Up until last night, I was able to upload files to S3 using the AWS PHP SDK without any problem. Since this morning (clock's changed because of the Daylight Saving) I've been getting `RequestTimeTooSkewed` error.

I compared AWS' and my server's time and they are identical (apart from AWS being on `GMT` and my server is on `UTC`)

```
wget https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/date --no-check-certificate --server-response
--2015-03-29 11:23:06--  https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/date
Resolving email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)... 207.171.162.129
Connecting to email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|207.171.162.129|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  x-amzn-RequestId: 981a9ae9-d5fd-11e4-8f83-65a61f41c957
  Content-Length: 29
  Date: Sun, 29 Mar 2015 10:23:08 GMT
2015-03-29 11:23:07 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

And on my server

```
date -u
Sun Mar 29 11:23:08 UTC 2015
```

Am I missing something here? Is my server being UTC a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time and AWS time are not identical.

For all practical purposes, UTC and GMT are exactly the same time zone.

Google `current time utc` and `current time gmt`.  Not only should you find that they are the same... you should also find that, for reasons not clear, your system clock is one hour ahead...which is wrong by any standard, since neither UTC nor GMT observes DST.

Your server time in GMT/UTC should not change when switching from/to summer time... so the question is, why did it change?  I notice you used `date -u`... if you've actually set your server time to some other time zone, you could be experiencing some kind of error from the double conversion (which is one reason the server clock should not be set to local time).

Comment: I haven't - at least knowingly - changed my server time zone. The machine was built using this vagrant file `https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/blob/master/Vagrantfile` and I haven't changed any thing time related after that.

Comment: Can you confirm that your `date -u` disagrees with Google's conception of the current time in UTC/GMT?  Also, what does just `date` show?  Same of different as `date -u`?  What about `cat /etc/timezone`?

Comment: `current time utc` Google search returns `16:29`  and my `date -u` returns `Sun Mar 29 17:29:21 UTC 2015` and `date` shows `Sun Mar 29 17:30:51 UTC 2015`. Aslo `cat /etc/timezone` returns `Etc/UTC`

Comment: How is your clock being set/maintained?

Comment: :) You lost me there. This is a virtual server on my machine (Mac) which I use for development. I do `vagrant up` and that's it.

Comment: Aha. What's the time zone on the Mac itself?  Local or GMT/UTC?  Is it accurate? What virtualization software are you running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74044/discussion-between-optimus-and-michael-sqlbot).

Comment: My local mac time zone is Time Zone: Europe/London and I am using Parallels Desktop 10 for virtualisation. My time - 17:55 - at the moment is correct

Comment: Actually you are right. I disabled the sync and I was able to upload to s3 without problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Please note according to this site --> http://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html

some countries switch time zones during the year.

"UTC, GMT and Daylight Saving Time
Neither UTC nor GMT ever change for Daylight Saving Time (DST). However, some of the countries that use GMT switch to different time zones during their DST period.
For example, the United Kingdom is not on GMT all year, it uses British Summer Time (BST), which is one hour ahead of GMT, during the summer months."